# mongo C# remove multiple records by id

Tags: c#, mongodb, database, nosql

I am trying to create a deleteAll method in mongo where I could delete multiple records in one go bu supplying the method a list of object ids to be deleted something like this

```
protected virtual  DeleteResult DeleteAll(List<ObjectId> listId, WriteConcern concern = null)
        {
            return MongoCollection
                .DeleteManyAsync(ItemWithListOfId(listId))
                    .Result;
        }

  protected FilterDefinition<T> ItemWithListOfId(List<ObjectId> id)
    {
        return Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);            
    }
```

it is giving no error but is not deleting any record as well.
Anyone any help?

Comment: take a look at http://pastie.org/4618039

Comment: I think this is some older version I do not have remove method all I can find is DeleteOneAsync and DeleteManyAync

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of the `Eq` filter, you need an **[`In`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_In.htm)** filter method to match the `id` values in a list, which is an implementation of the mongodb **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** query

```
protected FilterDefinition<T> ItemWithListOfId(List<ObjectId> id)
{
    return Builders<T>.Filter.In("_id", id);            
}
```